# Linq to SQL and SQL Server Compact Error: "There was an error parsing the query."

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I created a SQL server compact database (MyDatabase.sdf), and populated it with some data.  I then ran SQLMetal.exe and generated a linq to sql class (MyDatabase.mdf)

Now I'm trying to select all records from a table with a relatively straightforward select, and I get the error:

> "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 67,Token in error = MAX]"

Here is my select code:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ListItems()
{
    MyDatabase db_m = new MyDatabase("c:\mydatabase.sdf");
    return this.db_m.TestTable.Select(test => new Item()
        {
            ID = test.ID,
            Name = test.Name,
            RequestData = test.RequestData != null ? test.RequestData.ToString() : null,   
            Url = new System.Uri(test.Uri)
        }.AsEnumerable();
}
```

I've read that Linq to SQL works with Sql Compact, is there some other configuration I need to do?

Comment: Your code is clipped - impossible to tell what you're trying to do. Can you edit with full code?

Comment: @Rob Conery - I added in the missing code, but I don't think it is part of the problem, as I don't think that code isn't really part of the query that gets generated.

Comment: Oh, wait i see the problem.... checking if test.Request != null creates a case statement in the query.  I didn't realize that is how it worked!

Comment: How do I move that test out of the query?

Answer (score 5):

Could it be an errant NVARCHAR(MAX)?  I think I've seen an error like this before with sql compact edition, and as I recall it had to do with the fact that sql compact edition doesn't support the NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype.  This is also maybe why you see the "token in error = MAX" message in the exception?

Comment: You are SO right!  test.RequestData.ToString() causes a convert(nvarchar(MAX), RequestData) to be inserted into the SQL.

Comment: What would you replace nvarchar(max) with in a SQL CE database?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do the conversion on RequestData?  What does your class look like? Can you just set it like this?

```
    RequestData = test.RequestData
```

Comment: My class used string to hold request data, while the database used image.  I was converting the linq binary data to a string.  Not sure how I'd go about moving the conversion logic out of the linq code because I didn't want my class to know about any of the linq data types.  I ended up changing the data type in the database to ntext instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the approach of using a SQLMetal for a SQL Server compact edition in a Winforms app for Linq-to-sql
. 
After some problems i skipped the Linq-to-SQL Approach and went for the Linq-To-Entities approach. The syntax is like 99% the same for the query's i'm doing so ;-)

Also, when using the edmx designer, it's possible to easy update , delete and add tables.(with drag drop or Right-Click equivalent in the designer.)